# After Bluetooth OTA update, I can re-pair on iOS 9.2 phones but it won't work on iOS 9.3 phones

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ota, ios-bluetooth, bluegiga

I have an app that uses BLE to connect to a wearable device. I can update the firmware of the device via OTA. After the OTA process I can get re-paired to the wearable by calling connectPeripheral on the Central Manager. This works fine on iOS 9.2.

However, I have tested the same app on a phone with iOS 9.3 and doing the same thing causes problems. Instead of receiving one pairing request I get a lot of them. If I press pair or cancel, a new pairing request pop-up shows up. Eventually the pop-ups stop but the device isn't even paired to the app after.

Was there a change in iOS 9.3 that could be causing this? Anyone seen this behavior?

The bluetooth chip in the wearable device is a Bluegiga BLE113.

Comment: Can you please post where you call connectPeripheral? Also, are you searching for a specific UUID sequence?

Comment: Generally, once you OTA, odds are you've lost the bonds and need to 'forget' your pairing on the iOS side first.